# trying to add totals from specific cells in a column and move those totals over and up based on the color value of that cell

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the code I have.  I looking in column Q, finding a green cell.  Then I need to remember that is the row I am working with.  there are three columns to the right.  Then I keep going through the column to find another color, in this case color index 41, then move it to the row the green cell is in and to its appropriate column.  In this case 2 columns over. do this until the next green cell, then repeat.  My issue is if there are more than one of the color, in this case 41 it does not add it to the current total in the cell it gets moved to.  I need the destination cell to keep a total of the values I add to it, a running total as it would be.  I thought the
c2.value = cell2.value +c2.value,  would do the trick but it only takes the first value and doesn't add the second value to it.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each cell2 In ActiveSheet.Range("Q1:Q150000").Cells
    'remember the last green cell two columns to the right
    With cell2.Offset(0, 2)
        If .Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then Set c2 = .Cells(1)
    End With

    If cell2.Interior.ColorIndex = 41 Then
        If Not c2 Is Nothing Then 'have a green cell to copy to?
            c2.Value = cell2.Value + c2.Value  'add value to current value in cell
             Set c2 = Nothing     'clear this cell so we don't overwrite it later...
       End If
    End If
                                                 
       
Next cell2
```

Comment: Please show some sampl data and the desired output - otherwise it is difficult to understand what you want to achieve. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to enhance your question.

Comment: Never use Color.Index since that value is contingent on the theme the user is using.  Use the RGB or Hex value instead.